# Is there a convention when Linq to Entities convert to T-SQL?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

When we use LINQ2SQL queries, the result of the T-SQL it creates is very hard to learn. I want to know if there's a convention for LINQ statements converting to T-SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Even if there was, it could change between versions. The real question is: why do you care?

Comment: If I know the convention, I can write the query statement with better performance. But it seems really no conventions. Thanks for your reply